# Customize TabHost's button behavior

Tags: android, tabs, dialog, android-tabhost

I currently working on the application which having the `tabbar` containing four tab buttons. One of the tab button is "Information" tab. **`The information tab shows the information dialog containing detail info regarding to the activity.`**

**`Required`** :  Behavior of information tab is dynamic and it shows different information details to different activity.

Is it possible ? How to achieve this? or any other solution for that.

Another point : **`Is it possible to show the tab bar for entire application?`**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see your code will be like

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    // Tab for Photos
TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);


    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
    tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
```

you need to handle the events of tabs are as follows

```
tabHost.getChildAt(1).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            //Something to do

            return true; // do this if you dont want the tab to change
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```